# How to find whether a computer has joined domain of particular institution with help of powershell commands

Tags: powershell

I want to find out whether the user's computer has joined domain of particluar institution with help of powershell commands.

I tried the below command to check the domain join status but the command just shows whether domain joined or not, but what to do if I want to particularly check whether the domain == "XXX" of some company's network.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).PartOfDomain    
True
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if ((gwmi win32_computersystem).partofdomain -eq $true) {
    write-host -fore green "I am domain joined!"
} else {
    write-host -fore red "Ooops, workgroup!"
}
```

Comment: It worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track already, you're just querying the wrong property.

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Computersystem).Domain
```

Comment: The `Domain` property returns the Workgroup name if not joined to a domain. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem) _If the computer is not part of a domain, then the name of the workgroup is returned._

Comment: Can we run this command automatically from a UI to know whether user has joined right domain or not?

Comment: @reddy, for the user and not the computer?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot more out of the `Win32_Computersystem` class.
Below a helper function with which you can get that info:

```
function Get-ComputerInformation {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

        [switch]$AsHashTable
    )

    foreach ($computer in $ComputerName) {

        # System info
        $data = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer 

        $domainRole = switch ($data.DomainRole) {
            0 {'Standalone Workstation'; break}
            1 {'Member Workstation'; break}
            2 {'Standalone Server'; break}
            3 {'Member Server'; break}
            4 {'Backup Domain Controller'; break}
            5 {'Primary Domain Controller'}
        }

        $pcinfo = [ordered]@{}
        $pcinfo.'Computer'       = $data.Name
        $pcinfo.'Manufacturer'   = $data.Manufacturer
        $pcinfo.'Model'          = $data.Model
        $pcinfo.'PhysicalMemory' = "{0:N2} GB" -f ($data.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB)
        $pcinfo.'PartOfDomain'   = $data.PartOfDomain
        if ($data.PartOfDomain) {
            $pcinfo.'Domain'     = $data.Domain
        }
        else {
            $pcinfo.'WorkGroup'  = $data.Workgroup
        }
        $pcinfo.'DomainRole'     = $domainRole
        $pcinfo.'LoggedOnUser'   = $data.Username

        if ($AsHashTable) { $pcinfo }
        else { [PsCustomObject]$pcinfo }
    }
}
```